# ASP.NET reportviewer running batch reports in background

Tags: asp.net, .net, reporting-services, reportviewer, rdlc

I have a asp.net 4.0 page using reportviewer control to deliver reports.There is option to render reports in the page or to pdf/word.

There is also an option to provide a set of (or range of) parameters and the reportviewer would render multiple reports(sometimes over 100) in PDF/WORD.

The way this operates is when the "run batch" button is pressed, the page posts back and the local report is rendered for the available parameters or parameter combinations(into PDF reports).

This obviously causes a Postback and the postback takes very long to return.Is there a way to make the rendering of reports happen in background so the page can return immediately,

In the web I have seen vague references to background threads etc but nothing seems to work. Could somebody provide valuable ideas???

Comment: You put "There is also an option to provide a set of (or range of) parameters and the reportviewer would render multiple reports(sometimes over 100) in PDF/WORD." Are You able to point me in the direction of an article which covers this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

maybe if you post your request to a new page (if you can), it can solve your problem.